# Angular JSON - Use 'track by' expression to

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, angularjs

I am making a CRUD in angular + Php + MySql where I am facing a problem.
I have some data in database and want to show it on listing page.

To achieve this I made a ajax call in Angular and put the response in Scope Variable. If I print response its showing me below response but not able to show it in HTML. I am getting a problem i.e., :-

**Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: person in crew, Duplicate key: string:", Duplicate value: "\""**

Below is the Angular and HTML code :-

```
.controller('wrapperController', ['$scope','$rootScope','$http', function(scope,rootScope,http){

    http.post("server/viewRecords.php")
    .success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        scope.crew = response;

    });
}])

<tr ng-repeat="person in crew">
            <td>{{person.name}}</td>
            <td>{{person.desc}}</td>
            <td> <a href="#/edit/{{$index}}">Edit</a> </td>
            <td> <a href="#/delete/{{$index}}" data-ng-click="deleteRecord($index)">Delete</a> </td>
        </tr>
```

Please suggest why I am getting this error?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

AngularJS does not allow duplicates in a ng-repeat directive. Therefore, you can add `track by $index` into the ng-repeat as following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in crew track by $index">
            <td>{{person.name}}</td>
            <td>{{person.desc}}</td>
            <td> <a href="#/edit/{{$index}}">Edit</a> </td>
            <td> <a href="#/delete/{{$index}}" data-ng-click="deleteRecord($index)">Delete</a> </td>
</tr>
```

`Track by $index` tells angular to use `$index`, which is auto increment, as a key instead of each individual element in the array. So, it won't be duplicate anymore.

Comment: I already used this but it does not work. Its showing me blank number of records and data is also not correct.

Comment: @Ananddeepsingh What is the error message did you get?

Comment: @LVarayut - I am not getting any error message after using " track by $index" but its showing me blank records or you can say its not showing data from DB.

Comment: I have rename $scope to scope in function arguments. Please check below line i.e., :- 

.controller('wrapperController', ['$scope','$rootScope','$http', function(scope,rootScope,http)

Its still not works. :(

Comment: @Ananddeepsingh could you post your data in the scope.crew array?

Comment: @LVarayut - I am already sending response in scope.crew but still its not works.

One thing more I want to tell you that if I use simply {{crew}} in view. So it is working and showing me entire JSON response :-

<tr>
    <td>{{crew}}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>

Please suggest!!

Comment: What is the data in the $scope.crew?

Comment: Its entire JSON response

http.post("server/viewRecords.php")
  .success(function(response){
   console.log(response);
   scope.crew = response;

  });

Comment: 1[{"id":"1","name":"","desc":""},{"id":"2","name":"","desc":""},{"id":"3","name":"Anand Deep Singh","desc":"asdf"},{"id":"4","name":"Anand Deep Singh","desc":"asdf"},{"id":"5","name":"Anand Deep Singh","desc":"asdf"},{"id":"6","name":"deepa","desc":"123"},{"id":"7","name":"asdf","desc":"asdfasdf"},{"id":"8","name":"a","desc":"wew"},{"id":"9","name":"we23","desc":"sd"},{"id":"10","name":"Deepa","desc":"De"},{"id":"11","name":"Inder","desc":"asdf"},{"id":"12","name":"wewe","desc":"wewe"}]

Comment: 1[{"id":"1","name":"","desc":""},{"id":"2","name":"","desc":""},{"id":"3","name":"Anand Deep Singh","desc":"asdf"},{"id":"4","name":"Anand Deep Singh","desc":"asdf"},{"id":"5","name":"Anand Deep Singh","desc":"asdf"},{"id":"6","name":"deepa","desc":"123"},{"id":"7","name":"asdf","desc":"asdfasdf"},{"id":"8","name":"a","desc":"wew"},{"id":"9","name":"we23","desc":"sd"},{"id":"10","name":"Deepa","desc":"De"},{"id":"11","name":"Inder","desc":"asdf"},   {"id":"12","name":"wewe","desc":"wewe"}]

Comment: I have pasted it here. Hope you are able to watch it!!

Comment: Why there is `1` in front of your array? It should be `[{"id":"1","name":"","desc":""}, ...]`. Check your array again and make sure it's in a proper form.

Comment: I am not able to identify why this "1" is coming. :(

Comment: Try to post your code in the Plunkr. So, I can help you figure it out.

Comment: Hey @LVarayut - I have pasted my code in Plunker but unable to create database. Below is the URL for codebase.  

http://plnkr.co/edit/kYw7H6tnOL1GThpn4tfx?p=preview

Comment: I have verified your code. Everything seems good to me. I don't know exactly what's going on. Maybe, you can try to debug by using print_r in php and console.log() in javascript step by step.